# Linq expressions and extension methods to get property name

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, poco, system.componentmodel

I was looking at this post that describes a simple way to do databinding between POCO properties: [Data Binding POCO Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601880/data-binding-poco-properties)

One of the comments by Bevan included a simple Binder class that can be used to accomplish such data binding.  It works great for what I need but I would like to implement some of the suggestions that Bevan made to improve the class, namely:

- Checking that source and target are
  assigned
- Checking that the properties
  identified by sourcePropertyName and
  targetPropertyName exist
- Checking for type compatibility
  between the two properties

Also, given that specifying properties by string is error prone, you could use Linq expressions and extension methods instead. Then instead of writing

```
Binder.Bind( source, "Name", target, "Name")
```

you could write

```
source.Bind( Name => target.Name);
```

I'm pretty sure I can handle the first three (though feel free to include those changes) but I have no clue how to use Linq expressions and extension methods to be able to write code without using property name strings.

Any tips?

Here is the original code as found in the link:

```
public static class Binder
{

    public static void Bind(
        INotifyPropertyChanged source,
        string sourcePropertyName,
        INotifyPropertyChanged target,
        string targetPropertyName)
    {
        var sourceProperty
            = source.GetType().GetProperty(sourcePropertyName);
        var targetProperty
            = target.GetType().GetProperty(targetPropertyName);

        source.PropertyChanged +=
            (s, a) =>
            {
                var sourceValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);
                var targetValue = targetProperty.GetValue(target, null);
                if (!Object.Equals(sourceValue, targetValue))
                {
                    targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceValue, null);
                }
            };

        target.PropertyChanged +=
            (s, a) =>
            {
                var sourceValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);
                var targetValue = targetProperty.GetValue(target, null);
                if (!Object.Equals(sourceValue, targetValue))
                {
                    sourceProperty.SetValue(source, targetValue, null);
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get name of property as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following will return a property name as a string from a lambda expression:

```
public string PropertyName<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
{
  var lambda = (LambdaExpression)property;

  MemberExpression memberExpression;
  if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
  {
    var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
    memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
  }
  else
  {
    memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
  }

  return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int World { get; set; }
}

...
var c = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", PropertyName(() => c.World));
```

**UPDATE**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Bind<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>(this INotifyPropertyChanged source, Expression<Func<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>> bindExpression)
    {
        var expressionDetails = GetExpressionDetails<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>(bindExpression);
        var sourcePropertyName = expressionDetails.Item1;
        var destinationObject = expressionDetails.Item2;
        var destinationPropertyName = expressionDetails.Item3;

        // Do binding here
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", sourcePropertyName, destinationPropertyName);
    }

    private static Tuple<string, INotifyPropertyChanged, string> GetExpressionDetails<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>(Expression<Func<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>> bindExpression)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)bindExpression;

        ParameterExpression sourceExpression = lambda.Parameters.FirstOrDefault();
        MemberExpression destinationExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;

        var memberExpression = destinationExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;
        var constantExpression = memberExpression.Expression as ConstantExpression;
        var fieldInfo = memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
        var destinationObject = fieldInfo.GetValue(constantExpression.Value) as INotifyPropertyChanged;

        return new Tuple<string, INotifyPropertyChanged, string>(sourceExpression.Name, destinationObject, destinationExpression.Member.Name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class TestSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }        
}

public class TestDestination : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Id { get; set; }    
}

class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new TestSource();
        var y = new TestDestination();

        x.Bind<string, string>(Name => y.Id);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Do you know what I would need to do in order to write code like in my original question, something like source.Bind( Name => target.Name);?  I am not quite clear on how to combine the above Binder class and your method into an extension method.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a very rough implementation.  Note that I haven't done much (i.e. any) real testing on this!

Comment: Thanks! Two quick questions hopefully you can help with.  When I make the call to Bind, the second parameter is a member the current class, so I have something like x.Bind<string, string>(Name => Id); instead of x.Bind<string, string>(Name => y.Id).  In this case, the Bind fails since destinationExpression.Expression is a ConstantExpression instead of a MemberExpression.  I am not sure what I would need to change to make it work in that case. Second, is there a way to make it fail at compile time if a property name is incorrect, for example x.Bind<string, string>(Na123me => y.Id)?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to: [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

*(Cross-posting answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220748/1037948)*

I don't know if you need to bind to "subproperties", but inspecting the `lambda.Body` for `Member.Name` will only return the "final" property, not a "fully-qualified" property.

ex) `o => o.Thing1.Thing2` would result in `Thing2`, not `Thing1.Thing2`.

This is problematic when trying to use this method to simplify EntityFramework `DbSet.Include(string)` with expression overloads.

So you can "cheat" and parse the `Expression.ToString` instead.  Performance seemed comparable in my tests, so please correct me if this is a bad idea.

### The Extension Method

```
/// <summary>
/// Given an expression, extract the listed property name; similar to reflection but with familiar LINQ+lambdas.  Technique @via https://stackoverflow.com/a/16647343/1037948
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Cheats and uses the tostring output -- Should consult performance differences</remarks>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">the model type to extract property names</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">the value type of the expected property</typeparam>
/// <param name="propertySelector">expression that just selects a model property to be turned into a string</param>
/// <param name="delimiter">Expression toString delimiter to split from lambda param</param>
/// <param name="endTrim">Sometimes the Expression toString contains a method call, something like "Convert(x)", so we need to strip the closing part from the end</pa ram >
/// <returns>indicated property name</returns>
public static string GetPropertyName<TModel, TValue>(this Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> propertySelector, char delimiter = '.', char endTrim = ')') {

    var asString = propertySelector.ToString(); // gives you: "o => o.Whatever"
    var firstDelim = asString.IndexOf(delimiter); // make sure there is a beginning property indicator; the "." in "o.Whatever" -- this may not be necessary?

    return firstDelim < 0
        ? asString
        : asString.Substring(firstDelim+1).TrimEnd(endTrim);
}//--   fn  GetPropertyNameExtended
```

*(Checking for the delimiter might even be overkill)*

Answer (score 0):

This is likely more than or not exactly what you asked for but I've done something similar to handle mapping of a property between two objects:

```
public interface IModelViewPropagationItem<M, V>
    where M : BaseModel
    where V : IView
{
    void SyncToView(M model, V view);
    void SyncToModel(M model, V view);
}

public class ModelViewPropagationItem<M, V, T> : IModelViewPropagationItem<M, V>
    where M : BaseModel
    where V : IView
{
    private delegate void VoidDelegate();

    public Func<M, T> ModelValueGetter { get; private set; }
    public Action<M, T> ModelValueSetter { get; private set; }
    public Func<V, T> ViewValueGetter { get; private set; }
    public Action<V, T> ViewValueSetter { get; private set; }

    public ModelViewPropagationItem(Func<M, T> modelValueGetter, Action<V, T> viewValueSetter)
        : this(modelValueGetter, null, null, viewValueSetter)
    { }

    public ModelViewPropagationItem(Action<M, T> modelValueSetter, Func<V, T> viewValueGetter)
        : this(null, modelValueSetter, viewValueGetter, null)
    { }

    public ModelViewPropagationItem(Func<M, T> modelValueGetter, Action<M, T> modelValueSetter, Func<V, T> viewValueGetter, Action<V, T> viewValueSetter)
    {
        this.ModelValueGetter = modelValueGetter;
        this.ModelValueSetter = modelValueSetter;
        this.ViewValueGetter = viewValueGetter;
        this.ViewValueSetter = viewValueSetter;
    }

    public void SyncToView(M model, V view)
    {
        if (this.ViewValueSetter == null || this.ModelValueGetter == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Syncing to View is not supported for this instance.");

        this.ViewValueSetter(view, this.ModelValueGetter(model));
    }

    public void SyncToModel(M model, V view)
    {
        if (this.ModelValueSetter == null || this.ViewValueGetter == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Syncing to Model is not supported for this instance.");

        this.ModelValueSetter(model, this.ViewValueGetter(view));
    }
}
```

This allows you to create an instance of this object and then use "SyncToModel" and "SyncToView" to move values back and forth. The following piece that goes with this allows you to group multiple of these things and move data back and forth with one call:

```
public class ModelViewPropagationGroup<M, V> : List<IModelViewPropagationItem<M, V>>
    where M : BaseModel
    where V : IView
{
    public ModelViewPropagationGroup(params IModelViewPropagationItem<M, V>[] items)
    {
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public void SyncAllToView(M model, V view)
    {
        this.ForEach(o => o.SyncToView(model, view));
    }

    public void SyncAllToModel(M model, V view)
    {
        this.ForEach(o => o.SyncToModel(model, view));
    }
}
```

Usage would look something like this:

```
private static readonly ModelViewPropagationItem<LoginModel, ILoginView, string> UsernamePI = new ModelViewPropagationItem<LoginModel, ILoginView, string>(m => m.Username.Value, (m, x) => m.Username.Value = x, v => v.Username, (v, x) => v.Username = x);
private static readonly ModelViewPropagationItem<LoginModel, ILoginView, string> PasswordPI = new ModelViewPropagationItem<LoginModel, ILoginView, string>(m => m.Password.Value, (m, x) => m.Password.Value = x, v => v.Password, (v, x) => v.Password = x);
private static readonly ModelViewPropagationGroup<LoginModel, ILoginView> GeneralPG = new ModelViewPropagationGroup<LoginModel, ILoginView>(UsernamePI, PasswordPI);

public UserPrincipal Login_Click()
{
    GeneralPG.SyncAllToModel(this.Model, this.View);

    return this.Model.DoLogin();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

var pr = typeof(CCategory).GetProperties().Select(i => i.Name).ToList(); ;

Comment: Nice try but the compiler is not aware of the contents that will be gerenated in the list during run-time. Therefore, there is no intellisense advantage when it comes to refactoring and such.

Answer (score 0):

declaration:

```
    class Foo<T> {
            public string Bar<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expersion)
            {
                var lambda = (LambdaExpression)expersion;
                MemberExpression memberExpression;
                if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
                {
                    var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
                    memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
                }
                else
                {
                    memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
                }

                return memberExpression.Member.Name;
            }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var foo = new Foo<DummyType>();
    var propName = foo.Bar(d=>d.DummyProperty)
    Console.WriteLine(propName); //write "DummyProperty" string in shell
```