# Checking property name at compile time in lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, poco, system.componentmodel

In a previous question of mine, [Linq expressions and extension methods to get property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252176/linq-expressions-and-extension-methods-to-get-property-name) I asked about data binding between two POCO properties using expressions and extensions.  I got a helpful anser and it is working fine but I have a question about it.

Here is the code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Bind<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>(this INotifyPropertyChanged source, Expression<Func<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>> bindExpression)
    {
        var expressionDetails = GetExpressionDetails<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>(bindExpression);
        var sourcePropertyName = expressionDetails.Item1;
        var destinationObject = expressionDetails.Item2;
        var destinationPropertyName = expressionDetails.Item3;

        // Do binding here
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", sourcePropertyName, destinationPropertyName);
    }

    private static Tuple<string, INotifyPropertyChanged, string> GetExpressionDetails<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>(Expression<Func<TSourceProperty, TDestinationProperty>> bindExpression)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)bindExpression;

        ParameterExpression sourceExpression = lambda.Parameters.FirstOrDefault();
        MemberExpression destinationExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;

        var memberExpression = destinationExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;
        var constantExpression = memberExpression.Expression as ConstantExpression;
        var fieldInfo = memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
        var destinationObject = fieldInfo.GetValue(constantExpression.Value) as INotifyPropertyChanged;

        return new Tuple<string, INotifyPropertyChanged, string>(sourceExpression.Name, destinationObject, destinationExpression.Member.Name);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class TestSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }        
}

public class TestDestination : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Id { get; set; }    
}

class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new TestSource();
        var y = new TestDestination();

        x.Bind<string, string>(Name => y.Id);
    }    
}
```

My questions regarding the above are:

- When I make the call to Bind, the
  second parameter is a member of the
  current class, so I have something
  like x.Bind(Name =>
  Id); instead of x.Bind(Name => y.Id). In this case,
  the Bind fails since
  destinationExpression.Expression is a
  ConstantExpression instead of a
  MemberExpression. I am not sure what
  I would need to change to make it
  work in that case.
- Is there a way to make it fail at compile time if a property name is incorrect, for example x.Bind(Na123me => Id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The fact is, you're just using a trick to make it easier to produce an expression like this. But there is no way to enforce that the lambda expression follows a particular pattern at compile time. That's why technologies like LINQ to Entities tend to produce a lot of runtime exceptions.