# I have a c# class that returns some fields....but I want it to return a list of custom objects (I think!!!)

Tags: c#

This is a very noob question, but I have been googling and can't seem to work out the solution myself.
I have created a class that has a number of fields (below).  I am grabbing data from a .JSON file.

```
public class WeatherData
{
    //WeatherDatas
    public string airtemp { get; set; }
    public string apparenttemp { get; set; }
    public string windspeedkph { get; set; }
    public string windgustskph { get; set; }
    public string humidity { get; set; }
    public string dewpoint { get; set; }
    public string deltaT { get; set; }
    public string pressure { get; set; }

    public WeatherData(string json, int index)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jObbs = jsonObject["observations"];
        JToken jData = jObbs["data"];            
        airtemp = (string)jData[index]["air_temp"];
        apparenttemp = (string)jData[index]["apparent_t"];
        windspeedkph = (string)jData[index]["wind_spd_kmh"];
        windgustskph = (string)jData[index]["gust_kmh"];
        humidity = (string)jData[index]["rel_hum"];
        pressure = (string)jData[index]["press_qnh"];
    }
}
```

Using the above I can get the "airtemp" from "WeatherData.airtemp".  But due to some bells and whistles I want to add later what I really want to do is return not just the airtemp value but a field/property indicating the type of the value. For example something like:

`WeatherData.WeatherDatas.airtemp.value` & `WeatherData.WeatherDatas.airtemp.type`

Where `.value` would be air temp and `.type` be the string "airtemp".

I just can't seem to work out how to describe to google what I am trying to do.

Comment: Could you provide a sample JSON?

Comment: If `weatherData.WeatherData.airtype.type` is *always* going to return "airtemp", what's the benefit of it? And why are you using strings for all these inherently numeric values?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think "airtemp" was just a sample, and OP wants `{ 'airtemp' : 0, 'foo': 10 }` to become, for example, `new []{ new KeyValuePair<string, int>("airtemp", 0), new KeyValuePair<string, int>("foo", 10) };`

Comment: @Andre: If that's the aim, then the question is really unclear. (Well, there's little doubt about it - the question *is* unclear, IMO...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to look into using a dictionary. Dictionaries in c# use Key, Value pairs, so you may wish to create a dictionary of  Your key values would be the type, such as airtemp and the value values would be the value such as 32.54.

I recommend looking up this page if you're new to C# and want to learn Dictionaries, or any other cool C# things. http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is to use a `struct` to represent your instance attributes. S.t like this:

```
public struct Data
{
    public Type type; // if you want a string type (I don't know why) you can use a string type
    public string Value;
}
```

Then you class will look like this:

```
public class WeatherData
{
    //WeatherDatas
    public Data airtemp { get; set; }
    ...

    public WeatherData(string json, int index)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jObbs = jsonObject["observations"];
        JToken jData = jObbs["data"];            
        airtemp.Value = new Data((string)jData[index]["air_temp"], typeof(string));

        ...
    }
}
```

Note that: If you have too many properties in your class, consider using a class istead of struct.

Comment: Just an observation but is `Type` in the declaration in the `public Type type` a typo... should it be `string` too?

Comment: At the first look I though he want's to use the actual `Type`, but now that I looked again, you're right, he wants a `string` type, I don't know why though. Anyhow I've edited my answer. Tnx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explore types:

```
Type myType;
Object windy = "strong";
myType = windy.GetType();
```

Then use `typeof()` to see what you've got.

Not sure that dictionary is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can get property name without change your structure:

by example: `PropertyUtil<WeatherData>.GetName(x => x.airtemp);`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043028/440030
(source code)

```
public static class PropertyUtil<TSource>
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TResult>(
        Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> propertyExpression)
    {
       return (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own data type, instead of using string use something else Like;

```
public class UserString
{
    public Type _type{ get; set; }
    public string value{ get; set; }

    public UserString()
{
   _type = null;
   value = string.Empty;
}
}

public class WeatherData
{
    //WeatherDatas
    public UserString airtemp { get; set; }
    public UserString apparenttemp { get; set; }
    public UserString windspeedkph { get; set; }
    public UserString windgustskph { get; set; }
    public UserString humidity { get; set; }
    public UserString dewpoint { get; set; }
    public UserString deltaT { get; set; }
    public UserString pressure { get; set; }

    public WeatherData(string json, int index)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jObbs = jsonObject["observations"];
        JToken jData = jObbs["data"];            
        airtemp.value = (string)jData[index]["air_temp"];
//        airtemp._type = typeof(string); //Something like that.
        apparenttemp = (string)jData[index]["apparent_t"];
        windspeedkph = (string)jData[index]["wind_spd_kmh"];
        windgustskph = (string)jData[index]["gust_kmh"];
        humidity = (string)jData[index]["rel_hum"];
        pressure = (string)jData[index]["press_qnh"];
    }
}
```