# Extension method to get property name

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods, propertyinfo

I have an extension method to get property name as

```
public static string Name<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

I am calling it as

```
string Name = ((Expression<Func<DateTime>>)(() => this.PublishDateTime)).Name();
```

This is working fine and returns me `PublishDateTime` as string.

However I have an issue with the calling statement, it is looking too complex and I want some thing like this.

```
this.PublishDateTime.Name()
```

Can some one modify my extension method?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042937/how-can-i-add-this-method-as-an-extension-method-to-properties-of-my-class

Comment: This is not what I am asking for....

Comment: it's seems like exactly what you are asking for

Comment: I need this `this.PublishDateTime.Name()`, Would you tell me how to create extension method to do so? I already have done what is given in the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq expressions and extension methods to get property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252176/linq-expressions-and-extension-methods-to-get-property-name)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static string Name<T,TProp>(this T o, Expression<Func<T,TProp>> propertySelector)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

The usage is:

```
this.Name(x=>x.PublishDateTime);
```

Comment: Very nice, it solved my problem. Stylish calling `this.Name(x=>x.PublishDateTime);`

Comment: what is the minimum C# version or LINQ is required for this ?

Answer (score 11):

With C# 6.0, you can use:

```
nameof(PublishDateTime)
```

Comment: @Lali Get Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: So I need to wait for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `this.PublishDateTime.Name()`, as the only thing that will be passed into the extension method is the value or reference on which you call the extension method.

Whether it's a property, field, local variable or method result doesn't matter, it won't have a name that you can access inside the extension method.

The expression will be "verbose", see 
[How can I add this method as an extension method to properties of my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042937/how-can-i-add-this-method-as-an-extension-method-to-properties-of-my-class) (thanks [@Black0ut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376472/extension-method-to-get-property-name#comment52623816_32376472)) to put it in a static helper class.

Comment: Why I can't do this? When I am calling `this.PublishDateTime.Name()`, it means I am passing object to extension method. Now extension method should create expression by itself. I want to modify the extension method. There must be some soft solution for this...

Comment: You can do it, but it won't give you the member name. The extension method doesn't "know" it's being called on a member, and it doesn't have to be (`string foo = ""; var fooName = foo.Name()`). All that will be passed to the extension method is the value of, or a reference to the object you call it on.