# Getting the callee's name of an extension method

Tags: c#

I've built up a simple `ArgumentValidator` class in order to simplify argument preconditions in any given method. Most of them are `null` or bounds checks and it gets pretty tedious after a couple of

```
if (arg == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg));
```

So I've come up with the following set up:

```
public static class ArgumentValidator
{
    public interface IArgument<T>
    {
        string ParamName { get; }
        T Value { get; }
    }

    private class Argument<T>: IArgument<T>
    {
        public Argument(T argument, string paramName)
        {
            ParamName = paramName;
            Value = argument;
        }

        public string ParamName { get; }
        public T Value { get; }
    }

    public static IArgument<T> Validate<T>(this T argument, string paramName = null)
    {
        return new Argument<T>(argument, paramName ?? string.Empty);
    }

    public static IArgument<T> IsNotNull<T>(this IArgument<T> o)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(o.Value, null))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(o.ParamName);

        return o;
    }

    public static IArgument<T> IsSmallerThan<T, Q>(this IArgument<T> o, Q upperBound) where T : IComparable<Q> { ... }

    //etc.
}
```

And I can use it in the following way:

```
public Bar Foo(object flob)
{
     flob.Validate(nameof(flob)).IsNotNull().IsSmallerThan(flob.MaxValue);
}
```

Ideally I'd love to get rid of `nameof(flob)` in the `Validate` call and ultimately get rid of `Validate` alltogether; the only purpose of `Validate` is to avoid having to pass `nameof(...)` on every check down the chain.

Is there a way to get the name `flob` inside the `Validate()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing that with an extension method is not that easy. It is easier with a static method that takes an LINQ expression (derived from [devdigital's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252487/993547)):

```
public static T Validate<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> argument)
{
    var lambda = (LambdaExpression)argument;

    MemberExpression memberExpression;
    if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
    {
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
        memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
    }
    else
    {
        memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
    }

    string name = memberExpression.Member.Name;

    Delegate d = lambda.Compile();

    return (T)d.DynamicInvoke();
}
```

The `name` inside is the name of the property you put in the method:

```
MyMethods.Validate(() => o);
```

Since the `Validate` returns `T`, you can use that further on. This might not be as performing as you want it to be, but this is the only viable option.

It is possible to make this an extension method too, you have to create the expression yourself by hand:

```
Expression<Func<object>> f = () => o; // replace 'object' with your own type

f.Validate();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty interesting. Is doing something similar form an extension method even possible? I can live with `Validate` a being normal static method but I am curious as to why it being an extension method makes things harder.

Comment: Well, your property has to be an expression then... That isn't really working in my opinion.